# How to embed registration form properly so that I can have email confirmation with FosUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I have an Artist entity and a simple User Entity.

2 registrations possible on my website : one for the artist and one for a simple user.
Everything works fine with the user, he receives a confirmation email etc..It works great, but this time, when the artist registers on my website ( I embed the UserType of FosUserBundle so that the artist is also registered as an user on my website), the email confirmation to check the validity of the email entered and then enable the user is not sent like the simple user.

I know this is not happening as the action called for the artist registration is not the registerAction of the RegistrationController of FosUserBundle, but my action newAction of my ArtistController.

So I tried to use some code of the RegistrationController and the RegistrationFormHandler but I can't get it working as I don't manage to use for example the mailer interface inside my ArtistHandler and the token generator :

here is my ArtistHander.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\BrocBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use My\Bundle\BrocBundle\Entity\Artist;

use FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGenerator;

class ArtistHandler
{
    protected $form;
    protected $request;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em, Mailer $mailer, TokenGenerator $tokenGenerator)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->tokenGenerator = $tokenGenerator;
    }

    public function process()
    {
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
        {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            if ($this->form->isValid() ) 
            {
                $this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function onSuccess(Artist $artist)
    {

        $user = $artist->getUser();
        $user->setEnabled(false);

        if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) 
        {
            $user->setConfirmationToken($this->tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        }

        $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);


        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        $this->em->persist($artist);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE Ok finally here is what I have done but not sure it is the best way ? to do it and if one of you think there is a better way I would be very glad to do it rather than this one :

```
public function newAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $artist = new Artist();

    $mailer = new Mailer($this->get('mailer'), $this->get('router'), $this->get('templating'), array('confirmation.template'=> 'MyUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig', 'from_email' => array('confirmation' => 'mysenderadress@gmail.com')));
    $tokenGenerator = new TokenGenerator;
    $form = $this->createForm(new ArtistType, $artist);
    $formHandler = new ArtistHandler($form, $this->get('request'), $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(), $mailer, $tokenGenerator);

    $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');


    if ($formHandler->process()) 
    {   

        $authUser = false;
        if ($confirmationEnabled) {
            $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $artist->getUser()->getEmail());
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
        } else {
            $authUser = true;
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
        }

        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        if ($authUser) {
            $this->authenticateUser($artist->getUser(), $response);
        }

        return $response;
    }
    return $this->render('MyBrocBundle:Artist:new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: You should declare your objects (Mailer, TokenGenerator, ArtistHandler, ...) as service instead of instanciating them in the controller. As a rule of thumb, try not to write the keyword `new` for something else than entities and forms.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanto to use the mailer, you have to inject it, like you're doing with `EntityManager`

So:

- Add into your `service.yml` (or corrispective) the inject against your `ArtistHandler` class
- Modify `ArtistHandler` contructor

For more info you could also visit [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) (symfony2 documentation; a different approach)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have found a solution but I'm not sure it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used a different approach. Take a close look at `onSuccess` please

```
<?php

namespace  UsersBundle\Form\Handler;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler as BaseHandler;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use UsersBundle\Entity\User;
use AdminBundle\EntityDao\EntidadDao;
use AdminBundle\EntityDao\RolDao;
use UsersBundle\EntityDao\UserDao;

class RegistrationFormHandler extends BaseHandler{
    private $auditUser;
    private $entId;
    private $userInterno;

    private $container;

    public function __construct($form, $request, $userManager, $mailer, $container){
        parent::__construct($form, $request, $userManager, $mailer);
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function processIns($entId, $userInterno, $auditUserIns, $confirmation = false){
        $this->auditUser = $auditUserIns;
        $this->entId = $entId;
        $this->userInterno = $userInterno;

        return $this->process($confirmation);
    }

    /*public function processUpd($confirmation = false, $auditUserUpd){
        $this->auditUserUpd = $auditUserUpd;
        return $this->process($confirmation);
    }*/

    public function process($confirmation = false){
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $this->form->setData($user);

        if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod()) {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            if ($this->form->isValid()) {

                $tmp = $user->getIdUsuario();


                //Si es update
                if(empty($tmp) ){
                    $user->setAuditUserIns($this->auditUser);
                    $user->setAuditDateIns(new \DateTime());

                    $tmp = $this->entId;
                    if( !empty($tmp)){
                        $entidadDao = new EntidadDao($this->container->get("doctrine"));
                        $entidad = $entidadDao->getEntidad($this->entId);
                        $user->setEntidad($entidad);
                    }

                //Si es Insert    
                }else{
                    $userDao = new UserDao($this->container->get("doctrine"));

                    //Se obtiene el registro de la BD
                    $tmp = $userDao->getUserEspecifico($user->getIdUsuario());

                    //Se le asigna al Formulario
                    $this->form->setData($tmp);

                    //Se realiza un merge con lo que se envio en el Request
                    $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

                    $user = $tmp;
                    $tmp->setAuditUserUpd($this->auditUser);
                    $tmp->setAuditDateUpd(new \DateTime());
                }

                $rolDao= new RolDao($this->container->get("doctrine"));

                //Se asignan roles dependiendo del usuario interno
                if($this->userInterno =='false'){
                    $user->setRols($rolDao->getRolesEspecificos(
                            $user->getEntidad()->getEntImportador(),
                            $user->getEntidad()->getEntProductor(),
                            $user->getEntidad()->getEntComprador(),
                            $user->getEntidad()->getEntCompVend(),
                            $user->getUserTipo(),
                            $user->getUserInterno(),
                            $user->getUserInternoTipo()
                    ));
                }else{
                    $user->setRols($rolDao->getRolesEspecificos(
                            false,
                            false,
                            false,
                            false,
                            $user->getUserTipo(),
                            $user->getUserInterno(),
                            $user->getUserInternoTipo()
                    ));
                }


                //Hacer busqueda de los roles segun los campos de tipos y obtener el listado de objetos.
                $this->onSuccess($user, $confirmation);
                // do your custom logic here
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function onSuccess(UserInterface $user, $confirmation){
        // Note: if you plan on modifying the user then do it before calling the 
        // parent method as the parent method will flush the changes

        //parent::onSuccess($user, $confirmation);

        if ($confirmation) {
            $user->setEnabled(false);
            $user->generateConfirmationToken();
            $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);
        } else {
            $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
        }

        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        // otherwise add your functionality here
    }
}
```